# Проверка домашнего задания на Цикл While

Tags: python, циклы, инспекция-кода, pycharm

Сделал домашнее задание на цикл `while`.
Ниже будет код, но мне хотелось бы чтобы вы предложили свой вариант, чтобы сравнить как можно было бы сделать тоже самое, и получше понять цикл `while`. Если у меня есть ошибка в коде, пишите.

**Задача: цикл while**

Ежемесячная стипендия студента составляет `educational_grant` руб., а расходы на проживание превышают стипендию и составляют `expenses` руб. в месяц. Рост цен ежемесячно увеличивает расходы на 3%, кроме первого месяца
Составьте программу расчета суммы денег, которую необходимо единовременно попросить у родителей, чтобы можно было прожить учебный год (10 месяцев), используя только эти деньги и стипендию.

Формат вывода:
Студенту надо попросить ХХХ.ХХ рублей
`

```
educational_grant, expenses = 10000, 12000
mesyac = 0
procent = 0.03
prosit = 0
while mesyac != 9:
    expenses += expenses * procent
    mesyac += 1
    prosit = prosit + expenses
    print(mesyac, '%.2f' % expenses, '%.2f' % prosit,)

print('Студенту надо попросить', '%.2f' % prosit, 'рублей')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
`

Comment: +1 за качественно оформленный вопрос со своей попыткой решения)

Comment: ваш студент решил утаить от родителей тот факт, что он получает стипендию? ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В своем решении вы не учли стипендию и рост цен у вас начинается с первого месяца, а не со второго.

```
In [229]: total_exp, month = 0, 0
     ...: while month < 10:
     ...:     total_exp += expenses * 1.03**month
     ...:     print(f"month: {month+1}, expenses: {total_exp}")
     ...:     month += 1
     ...: res = total_exp - 10*educational_grant
     ...: print(res)
month: 1, expenses: 12000.0
month: 2, expenses: 24360.0
month: 3, expenses: 37090.8
month: 4, expenses: 50203.524000000005
month: 5, expenses: 63709.629720000004
month: 6, expenses: 77620.9186116
month: 7, expenses: 91949.54616994801
month: 8, expenses: 106708.03255504645
month: 9, expenses: 121909.27353169784
month: 10, expenses: 137566.55173764878
37566.551737648784
```

Answer (score 4):

Следите за условиями. Месяцев 10. Рост цен - кроме первого месяца.
И где учитывается стипон?

```
educational_grant, expenses = 10000, 12000
mesyac = 0
procent = 0.03
prosit = 0
while mesyac < 10:
    mesyac += 1
    nehvatat= expenses - educational_grant
    print(mesyac, '%.2f' % expenses, '%.2f' % nehvatat,)
    prosit += nehvatat
    expenses += expenses * procent

print('Студенту всего надо попросить', '%.2f' % prosit, 'рублей')

1 12000.00 2000.00
2 12360.00 2360.00
3 12730.80 2730.80
4 13112.72 3112.72
5 13506.11 3506.11
6 13911.29 3911.29
7 14328.63 4328.63
8 14758.49 4758.49
9 15201.24 5201.24
10 15657.28 5657.28
Студенту всего надо попросить 37566.55 рублей
```

Comment: Неправильно понял условие  "кроме первого месяца", поэтому указал 9 месяцев. На собственных ошибках, и с Вашей поддержкой, мне проще понять как работает цикл while. Спасибо